# trying to install terminal window managers

Tags: compiling, window-manager

I'd like to try some terminal window managers such as Viper Window Manager (VWM) and Twin ("Textmode WINdow"), but I'm having difficulties getting them running in Ubuntu. Are packages available for these or other similar efforts or are there some guidelines for installation?

---

EDIT: I have added below a description of the specific difficulties I am encountering. Initially, I describe my attempt at installing Viper Window Manager, then I describe my attempt at installing Twin. For both attempts, problems are encountered in compiling. For the case of Viper Window Manager, there are many undefined references. For the case of Twin, there appears to be a formatting problem in the Make procedures. I do not know how to proceed with either of these problems and would appreciate any ideas you might have. Thanks.

## Viper Window Manager

The prerequisites listed for Viper Window Manager are as follows:

- glib 2.8+
- libpseudo
- libviper 1.4.5+
- libgpm
- ncurses 5.4+

### install glib 2.40.0

```
wget http://ftp.acc.umu.se/pub/GNOME/sources/glib/2.40/glib-2.40.0.tar.xz
tar -xvf glib-2.40.0.tar.xz
cd glib-2.40.0/
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

### install libpseudo

```
wget http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libpseudo/libpseudo-1.2.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf libpseudo-1.2.0.tar.gz
cd libpseudo/
make
sudo make install
```

### install libgpm, ncurses and libviper

```
wget http://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/libviper/libviper-1.4.6.tar.gz
tar -xvf libviper-1.4.6.tar.gz
cd libviper/
sudo apt-get install -y ncurses-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libgpm-dev
make
sudo make install
# The file viper.h is in the directory /usr/local/include now.
# The file libviper.so is in the directory /usr/local/lib now.
```

### install Viper Window Manager

```
wget http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/vwm/vwm-2.1.3.tar.gz
tar -xvf vwm-2.1.3.tar.gz
cd cd vwm/
make
```

At this point, there is a problem. The *abbreviated* terminal output is as follows:

```
/tmp/ccNnGI2W.o: In function `vwm_init':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:200: undefined reference to `viper_screen_get_wallpaper'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:202: undefined reference to `g_malloc0'
/tmp/ccNnGI2W.o: In function `main':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:87: undefined reference to `g_module_supported'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:130: undefined reference to `g_thread_init'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:132: undefined reference to `viper_init'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:134: undefined reference to `viper_set_border_agent'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:135: undefined reference to `viper_set_border_agent'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:142: undefined reference to `viper_kmio_dispatch_set_hook'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:145: undefined reference to `viper_screen_redraw'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:149: undefined reference to `psthread_init'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:150: undefined reference to `psthread_add'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:151: undefined reference to `psthread_add'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:178: undefined reference to `psthread_run'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:172: undefined reference to `shmq_msg_get'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:181: undefined reference to `psthread_run'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm.c:186: undefined reference to `viper_end'
/tmp/ccdfRjqI.o: In function `vwm_bkgd_simple':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:54: undefined reference to `viper_thread_enter'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:56: undefined reference to `viper_wresize'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:65: undefined reference to `window_fill'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:70: undefined reference to `wattr_on'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:71: undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:72: undefined reference to `wattr_on'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:74: undefined reference to `viper_thread_leave'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:59: undefined reference to `viper_color_pair'
/tmp/ccdfRjqI.o: In function `vwm_bkgd_bricks':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:110: undefined reference to `viper_thread_enter'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:112: undefined reference to `viper_wresize'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:113: undefined reference to `wattr_off'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:146: undefined reference to `wattr_on'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:147: undefined reference to `mvwprintw'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:148: undefined reference to `wattr_on'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:150: undefined reference to `viper_thread_leave'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:121: undefined reference to `viper_color_pair'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:128: undefined reference to `wmove'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:129: undefined reference to `waddch'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:136: undefined reference to `viper_color_pair'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_bkgd.c:141: undefined reference to `window_fill'

... many similar errors, removed for the purposes of post brevity...

/tmp/ccHLYQ3M.o: In function `vwm_sigset':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_signals.c:38: undefined reference to `g_malloc0'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_signals.c:46: undefined reference to `g_free'
/tmp/ccHLYQ3M.o: In function `vwm_backtrace':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_signals.c:61: undefined reference to `endwin'
/tmp/ccrc2yXA.o: In function `vwm_fmod_wndlist':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:45: undefined reference to `viper_window_find_by_class'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:47: undefined reference to `viper_thread_enter'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:49: undefined reference to `viper_deck_get_wndlist'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:50: undefined reference to `g_strv_length'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:58: undefined reference to `viper_menu_create'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:60: undefined reference to `g_malloc0'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:63: undefined reference to `set_menu_format'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:65: undefined reference to `set_menu_mark'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:67: undefined reference to `scale_menu'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:71: undefined reference to `viper_window_create'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:72: undefined reference to `viper_menu_bind'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:76: undefined reference to `viper_color_pair'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:75: undefined reference to `set_menu_fore'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:77: undefined reference to `viper_color_pair'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:77: undefined reference to `set_menu_back'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:82: undefined reference to `viper_event_set'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:84: undefined reference to `viper_window_set_key_func'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:85: undefined reference to `viper_window_set_userptr'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:86: undefined reference to `viper_window_set_state'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:88: undefined reference to `viper_thread_leave'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:89: undefined reference to `g_strfreev'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:54: undefined reference to `viper_thread_leave'
/tmp/ccrc2yXA.o: In function `vwm_fmod_wndlist_ON_DESTROY':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:111: undefined reference to `viper_thread_enter'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:127: undefined reference to `viper_menu_destroy'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:129: undefined reference to `viper_thread_leave'
/tmp/ccrc2yXA.o: In function `vwm_fmod_wndlist_ON_KEYSTROKE':
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:141: undefined reference to `viper_window_get_userptr'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:151: undefined reference to `viper_thread_enter'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:170: undefined reference to `viper_window_redraw'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:171: undefined reference to `viper_thread_leave'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:156: undefined reference to `current_item'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:158: undefined reference to `viper_window_destroy'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:166: undefined reference to `viper_thread_leave'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:145: undefined reference to `menu_driver'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:146: undefined reference to `getmouse'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:151: undefined reference to `viper_thread_enter'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:153: undefined reference to `menu_driver'
/home/user/VWM/vwm/vwm_wndlist.c:152: undefined reference to `menu_driver'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [vwm] Error 1
```

## Twin

### install Twin

```
wget http://netcologne.dl.sourceforge.net/project/twin/twin/0.6.2/twin-0.6.2.tar.gz
tar -xvf twin-0.6.2.tar.gz
cd twin-0.6.2/
./configure
make
```

At this point, there is a problem. The terminal output is as follows:

```
make -C include
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/include'
make autogen -C Tutf
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/include/Tutf'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `autogen'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/include/Tutf'
make autogen -C Tw
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/include/Tw'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `autogen'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/include/Tw'
make autogen -C TT
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/include/TT'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `autogen'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/include/TT'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/include'
make -C docs
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/docs'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/docs'
make -C themes
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/themes'
make -C hw_gfx
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/themes/hw_gfx'
ln -f -s ShinyMetal_6x13.xpm default_6x13.xpm
ln -f -s absolute-e_8x16.xpm default_8x16.xpm
ln -f -s Ganymede_9x19.xpm default_9x19.xpm
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/themes/hw_gfx'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/themes'
make -C libs
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/libs'
make -C libTutf
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/libs/libTutf'
gcc -D_REENTRANT -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wshadow -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-pointer-sign -D_GNU_SOURCE  -I../../include  -s  ../../scripts/endianity.c -o ../../scripts/Endianity
../../scripts/Endianity > ../../include/Tw/endianity.h
gcc -D_REENTRANT -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wshadow -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-pointer-sign -D_GNU_SOURCE  -I../../include   -s  ../../scripts/getsizes.c -o ../../scripts/Getsizes
../../scripts/Getsizes > ../../include/Tw/datasizes.h
gcc -D_REENTRANT -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -Wall -Wshadow -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-pointer-sign -D_GNU_SOURCE  -I../../include  -s  ../../scripts/mkdep.c -o ../../scripts/Mkdep
cat ../../scripts/unitypes32.in > ../../include/Tw/uni_types.h
building  ../../.hdepend
building  ../../include/Tw/Twautoconf.h
/bin/bash ../../scripts/Configure.tty "../../" "../../" < /dev/null > /dev/null || \
    /bin/sh ../../scripts/Configure.fallback "../../" "../../" < /dev/null > /dev/null
building  .depend
building  .modules
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/libs/libTutf'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/libs/libTutf'
.modules:1: *** missing separator. Stop.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/libs/libTutf'
make[1]: *** [build-dir-libTutf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/user/Twin/twin-0.6.2/libs'
make: *** [build-dir-libs] Error 2
```

Comment: I don't think you'll find Ubuntu packages, I very much doubt there's much interest in something like that in the Ubuntu world. I suggest you [edit] your question and explain what your difficulties are. You should be able to compile and install from source. Have you tried?

Comment: Thanks for your comments and suggestions. My interest in these interfaces is based both on curiosity (I have never used extensive text-mode window managers and would like to) and practicality (I have heard good reports on their remote use (e.g. via SSH). I have indeed attempted to compile from source and have run into difficulties for both Viper Window Manager and Twin. I have edited my post to give specific information on these problems. Let me know if you have any thoughts! :)

Comment: If you manage to build VMW, check [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/390390)

Comment: Why did you install the libraries from source instead of using the ones available in the package repositories?

Comment: I installed ncurses and libgpm from packages, but, for the others, I didn't see an obvious way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

**Twin**

Twin Windows Manager can Be installed in 14.04 by installing `libtwin0` package. For complete installation, follow the following command :

```
sudo apt-get install libtwin0 multiarch-support libc6 libjpeg8 libpng12-0 libx11-6 zlib1g libtwin-dev gextractwinicons
```

Syntax for use Twin in Commandline is :

```
twin [OPTION [...]]
```

You can find options by :

```
twin -h
```

You can also read the [manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/twin.1.html) article.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This looks promising. Having done this, would you know how I could proceed to try to run Twin? When I try to execute either the command ```twin``` or ```twstart```, they are not found.

Answer (score 1):

**Twin**

This worked for me on ubuntu 16.04:

```
git clone https://github.com/cosmos72/twin
cd twin
./configure
make
sudo make install
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib
twin
```